# ASP.net REST API returns different data local or on azure

Tags: c#, rest, azure

So I built this API that returns data about devices. When I run this project localy, the result my requests give me are correct:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "x1",
    "LocationName": "Floor 2"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Name": "x2",
    "LocationName": "Floor 2"
  }
]
```

When I publish this project to Azure and make the exact same request this is what I get:

```
 "Request": {
    "AlwaysMultipartFormData": false,
    "JsonSerializer": {
      "DateFormat": null,
      "RootElement": null,
      "Namespace": null,
      "ContentType": "application/json"
    },
    "XmlSerializer": {
      "RootElement": null,
      "Namespace": null,
      "DateFormat": null,
      "ContentType": "text/xml"
    },
    "ResponseWriter": null,
    "UseDefaultCredentials": false,
    "Parameters": [
      {
        "Name": "Accept",
        "Value": "application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml",
        "Type": 3,
        "ContentType": null
      }
    ],
    "Files": [],
    "Method": 0,
    "Resource": "devices",
    "RequestFormat": 1,
    "RootElement": null,
    "OnBeforeDeserialization": {
      "Delegate": {
        "type": "System.Action`1[[RestSharp.IRestResponse, RestSharp, Version=105.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]",
        "assembly": "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
        "target": null,
        "targetTypeAssembly": "RestSharp, Version=105.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
        "targetTypeName": "RestSharp.RestRequest",
        "methodName": "<.ctor>b__0",
        "delegateEntry": null
      },
      "method0": {
        "Name": "<.ctor>b__0",
        "AssemblyName": "RestSharp, Version=105.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
        "ClassName": "RestSharp.RestRequest",
        "Signature": "Void <.ctor>b__0(RestSharp.IRestResponse)",
        "Signature2": "System.Void <.ctor>b__0(RestSharp.IRestResponse)",
        "MemberType": 8,
        "GenericArguments": null
      }
    },
    "DateFormat": null,
    "XmlNamespace": null,
    "Credentials": null,
    "UserState": null,
    "Timeout": 0,
    "ReadWriteTimeout": 0,
    "Attempts": 1
  },
  "ContentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "ContentLength": -1,
  "ContentEncoding": "",
  "Content": "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"$id\": \"1\",\r\n    \"id\": \"1\",\r\n    \"name\": \"x1\",\r\n    \"deviceTypeName\": \"Brickstream\",\r\n    \"lastSeen\":....
```

It looks like a string representation of a HttpResponseMessage object. As you can see under contents, thats the same output of when I did the request locally. Now is the question, what am I doing wrong here?

Code:

```
[Route("")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAllDevicesLocation(string location)
{
    var request = new RestRequest();
    request = new RestRequest($"devices", Method.GET);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    string serializedItemsFromBackend = response.Content;
    var deserializedItemsFromBackend = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DeviceModels>>(serializedItemsFromBackend);
    List<DeviceModels> list = new List<DeviceModels>();

    foreach (DeviceModels device in deserializedItemsFromBackend)
    {
        if (device.LocationName.Equals(location))
        {
            list.Add(device);
        }
    }
    if (list.Count > 0)
    {
        return CreateResponse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list));
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Devices in that area wasn't found.");
}
```

I can swear that this worked yesterday. My other endpoints work just fine..

EDIT     This endpoint gives me correct results both locally and on azure::

```
   [Route("{name}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetDevice(string name)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest();
            request = new RestRequest($"devices", Method.GET);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            string serializedItemsFromBackend = response.Content;
            var deserializedItemsFromBackend = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DeviceModels>>(serializedItemsFromBackend);

            foreach (DeviceModels device in deserializedItemsFromBackend)
            {
                if (device.Name.Equals(name))
                {
                    return CreateResponse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(device));
                }
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Device with that name wasn't found.");
        }
```

Comment: Is this a WebApp or something different?

Comment: It's a WebApp.-

Comment: You will have to extract content tag and then use deserialization on that particular tag. or you will need to modify deserialization to include response handling also

Comment: Are you using some kind of a custom serializer?

Comment: No, I'm using Newtonsoft standard and I could swear that this worked just fine yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I create the following sample to reproduce the issue on my side, the sample that returns an `HttpResponseMessage` works fine both on local and Azure website. You could create a new Web API project to convert the return value directly into an HTTP response message and publish the project to a new Azure website as I did to check if it works as expected.

***My controller action***

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        List<DeviceModels> list = new List<DeviceModels>();
        list.Add(new DeviceModels() { Id = "1", Name = "x1", LocationName = "Floor 2" });
        list.Add(new DeviceModels() { Id = "2", Name = "x2", LocationName = "Floor 2" });

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list));

        return response;
     }
}
```

[image]

If possible, you could modify your controller action to return json string directly.

```
public string GetAllDevicesLocation(string location)
{
    //code logic

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
}
```

Besides, please make sure you still could get correct result from action `GetAllDevicesLocation` from your local project. And you could [remote debug your web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#a-nameremotedebugaremote-debugging-web-apps) to trace the variable `response` and check if the method `CreateResponse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list))` works as it run on your local project.

If you could provide us a sample that could reproduce the issue, which will help us find and fix the issue.